# Do tags apply to the question or the answer?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently asked for help with a bug, where I had little idea what the problem was or how to fix it.

I tagged my question with some basic things, like what language I was using, etc. And the person who answered my question (correctly. thanks!) also deleted a couple of my tags, on the theory that my question was about an operating system feature and not a feature in the language/api I was using.

I'm not sure if I agree with that, I think the tags should relate to the question, not the answer. Other people with the same problem as me also might not know enough about the answer to find my question, since it's not tagged how they would expect it to be.

Specifically, I was creating a file, with objective-c/cocoa, and the resulting file had a boolean flag attached to it that I didn't want. It turned out the flag was being set by a security daemon and not by my code, and the fix was to add some metadata to my app to change the daemon's behaviour. I think "objective-c" and "cocoa" are valid tags for my question, but clearly not for the answer.

Should I put my tags back?

This is the question: [How can I stop my app from setting the "quarantine" bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544874/how-can-i-stop-my-app-from-setting-the-quarantine-bit)

Comment: To expand on @Roberts answer, people will most likely google search for the problem and land on to the solution. The tags don't **usually** facilitate searching for a problem.

Comment: By my understanding of google's algorithm (as a web programmer with 10 years experience working at an online marketing company), I'm pretty sure tags have a huge effect on a question's position in a google search result. The page listing questions in the "php" tag would have an insanely high pagerank for that search term, high enough any other page it links to would also have very high pagerank for "php".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tags apply to the question, not the answers.

The editor who removed the tags is being unnecessarily pedantic:

> The file quarantine system (which is the crux of your problem) is part
>   of Launch Services, and isn't specific to either Cocoa or Objective-C.

But you may not have known that when you posted the question, and neither will others searching for a solution to the same problem.