# How to review suggested edit adding answer-related tag

Tags: discussion, tags, review, suggested-edits

I was reviewing suggested edits and encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21825862/1782465), where the suggested edit was adding [rounding](/questions/tagged/rounding). I don't feel this tag is appropriate to the question - the question doesn't mention rounding at all.

At the same time, the *answers* to the question might very well have to deal with rounding. So it looks to me that while the tag is not appropriate to the question, it is/could be appropriate to the answers to it.

How would one evaluate such case? Is an answer-only tag appropriate for a question? Or do I misunderstand and the tag is actually applicable to the question itself as well?

Comment: Related: [Retagging to include tags for possible solutions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157688/retagging-to-include-tags-for-possible-solutions)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Hm, my search-fu is obviously below par :-( I didn't find that (nor those linked from it). Aparently, searching for "tag" doesn't really bring up "retagging" questions.

Comment: Also related: [Do tags apply to the question or the answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125201/do-tags-apply-to-the-question-or-the-answer), is isn't in the related list of my earlier related post.

Comment: If you disagree with a suggested edit then reject it. No need to overthink it so much. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, sure. But I'm trying to be as good a reviewer as possible, so I'm trying to attune my agreement with that of the community.

Comment: @Angew sure and +1 for that but I fear community consensus is very rare, especially in edits. More likely you'll get different answers, each and his own personal opinion. So if Jon says "approve" and Bob says "reject", what will you do?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Follow my judgment, but this time knowing I am not going against community consensus (because there is none). But I've gained a lot of relevant links from my question, which I consider valuable of itself.

Comment: Unrelated: I appreciate the edit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

How I look at it, tags are used by people with expertise to find questions they can answer with that expertise. People who have the same problem use google to find questions, which uses the question body more than any tag you attach to it.

I personally consider [rounding](/questions/tagged/rounding) a minor tag. It's awfully shallow, meaning it will most likely not attract many people that know the answer.

In that light:

- if a question doesn't have answers, or useful answers yet, I accept the edit.
- if a question already has plenty of answers, and no other changes were made, I reject with the 'too minor' reason: The suggested edit doesn't improve the question in any way.