# Should questions be retroactively tagged based on answers?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

Sorry if this has already been brought up before. The closest question I could find was [Do tags apply to the question or the answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125201) but that question is asking about a case where an editor deletes tags unrelated to the answer. I'm asking if new tags should be added based on the answer.

Here is an imaginary scenario:

Someone asks the question "What is the 4-legged enemy of dogs". The available tags are [dog](/questions/tagged/dog), [cat](/questions/tagged/cat) and [4-legged-animal](/questions/tagged/4-legged-animal). The question is tagged with [4-legged-animal](/questions/tagged/4-legged-animal) and [dog](/questions/tagged/dog).

My question is: should an editor add the [cat](/questions/tagged/cat) tag even though [cat](/questions/tagged/cat) is the answer? One one hand, I feel that it would be weird for a question to have that tag when it is what the OP is asking for. On the other hand, [cat](/questions/tagged/cat) would be so obvious that an editor may not hesitate to add it. Plus someone searching for that tag might find useful information in the question or answer. A related question is: Are questions only tagged based on the knowledge of the OP (surmised by the question)?

Comment: Also discussed here: [Should I add a tag to a question, if it's associated with the marked answer?](/q/149345/289905), [Should I retag a question with a tag that is based on the answer and not the question?](/q/26913/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks for finding those. I think my question is a duplicate of that last one.

Comment: Tags are put on the question to show what the question is about. If they can't be applied without knowing the answer, they're not what the question concerns.

Comment: @Nij how about after the question is answered (and accepted)?

Comment: A note - this may be site specific. For example, when M&TV accepted movie identification questions, adding the title tag of the movie after it was identified was not OK.

Comment: Tags are primarily for answerers to find / filter questions they want to answer. So on re-tagging you should ask yourself: *Do these tags bring the question in front of the right experts. If not: add/remove/replace tags.* If you hate cats you probably have the tag cat in your ignore list and as dog expert you would love to  blame the feline for being enemies. So no, adding cat in this case is not bringing the right audience to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I retag a question with a tag that is based on the answer and not the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26913/should-i-retag-a-question-with-a-tag-that-is-based-on-the-answer-and-not-the-que)

Comment: No. Why would being accepted have anything to do with the reason that tags are about the question, never the answer.

Comment: It doesn't have to be imaginary. An example is *[Flutter command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652071)*. There is nothing in the question (title, body, and tags) to indicate it is for macOS. But there is information in comments, and the likely underlying issue is changing of ***the default shell*** from Bash to [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) with [macOS v10.15 (Catalina)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina). Meanwhile, lots of answers have been added for Windows and Linux as well.